# 3D Touch on UITextView

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextview, 3dtouch

Is it possible to implement 3D Touch with UITextView?
I tried this example. And this method hadn't called by system when I tapped on any view on the screen. As I read there is no way to use 3D touch with UITapGestureRecognizer. So is there any ways to do this?

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    print("test0")

    if let touch = touches.first {

        print("test1")

            if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapability.available {
                print("test2")

                print("FORCE TOUCH VALUE \(touch.force)")

            }

    }

}
```

Comment: As I figured out, there is no way to do it easy. Just more low-level ways.